# How is an integer converted to a string and vice versa?

Tags: types, type-conversion

Functions for converting between data types are usually built into programming languages. Sometimes they are implemented in library or include files. I can imagine converting an integer to a character through the use of a lot of conditional statements, but I'm sure that's not how it's actually done. What programming is used to provide these conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go in python

```
x = 12345
chrs = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
s = ''
while x > 0:
  r = x % 10
  s = chrs[r] + s
  x = x / 10
```

(very inefficient but as clear as I can make it)
(idea is to get remainder after division by 10 and append to string)
(you should build strings by `joining` an array in most programming languages)

Comment: Well, I meant low level. Like what is done to convert between them. A change in another variable marking the type, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Some conversions can be done with the ASCII table :

The ASCII table contains printable character, including numbers. The nice thing is that every number between 0 and 9 are consecutive, therefore, it's fairly easy to get the char value of a number.

[image]

When you look at the ASCII table, you'll see that the char value of '0' is 48, so if n is between 0 and 9, the char value of n is 48+n

Suppose your number is 45, and you want to convert it to a String.

we take the last digit, which is 5. We create a string, and we set the value of the string to 48+5=53, the ASCII code for '5'. Now, repeat this process for every digit, and you'll get your string

To convert a string back to integer, you do the same process in the other way :

with the same example, we have "45". We look at '4', ASCII code 52, 52-48 = 4. We store this thing into an integer, and continue looping through the string, multiplying by ten before evey iterations.

I've illustrated this example [here](http://ideone.com/qoU31u), it's a bit dirty but I hope it's explicit. The code is as follow :

```
string number = "";
number = (char)53 + number;
number = (char)52 + number;
cout << "Expected : a string equals to 45" << endl;
cout << number << endl;


int numberInt = ('4'-48)*10+'5'-48;
cout << "Expected : an integer equals to 45" << endl;
cout << numberInt<<endl;
```